# Combining multiple queries(select, update) (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I am making a project to challange myself doing complex script(despite my skills are not that high). All the things were good untill now.
I faced an issue(lack of knowedge) for doing the following:

Table users:

[users http://cloud.screenpresso.com/5rExb/2016-02-15_18h09_05.png](http://cloud.screenpresso.com/5rExb/2016-02-15_18h09_05.png)

Table rounds:

[rounds http://cloud.screenpresso.com/Gmxsg/2016-02-15_18h09_52.png](http://cloud.screenpresso.com/Gmxsg/2016-02-15_18h09_52.png)

Table bets:

[bets http://cloud.screenpresso.com/bWVZe/2016-02-15_18h10_26.png](http://cloud.screenpresso.com/bWVZe/2016-02-15_18h10_26.png)

The thing is that i want to update everybody's(on the people who put bet on the winning round) balance in 1 query(I can do it by fetching everyone's bet insert it in to PHP, and run new update query) but i think this will not be the right thing to do.
Users have 3 ranges to bet as you can see in the bets table.:

- 0-0
- 1-7
- 7-14

Can you please assist me with explanation/answer what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Will [IODKU](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) do the task?